# How to start and stop mongodb server on windows?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, shell, mongodb-shell

**To Start**

```
   C:\Windows\System32>net start MongoDB
    The MongoDB service is starting.
    The MongoDB service was started successfully.
```

**To Stop**

```
C:\Windows\System32>net stop MongoDB
The MongoDB service is stopping.
The MongoDB service was stopped successfully.
```

Answer (score 3):

First you have install as a service named `MongoDB`:

Refer this **[link](https://medium.com/stackfame/run-mongodb-as-a-service-in-windows-b0acd3a4b712)** to `Run MongoDB as a Service` in Windows

Then you can use the `net start MongoDB` and `net stop MongoDB`

Answer (score 2):

got to search
[image]

and

search MongoDB klik start

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first. you should run it as administrator the next cmd

```
 net stop MongoDB
```

and process finished.